# Adding picturebox at runtime and changing their properties (from another method)

Tags: c#

I'm adding a PictureBox to a Form at runtime in C# and it does work (I think). Only problem is I can't change the properties of the PictureBox from outside nor from inside the method, eg. I can't even change the BackColor.

This is my attempt:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  PictureBox canvas = new PictureBox();
  canvas.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  canvas.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

The PictureBox should now fill the entire Form and have a red background but it doesn't work.

Also, how do I add the PictureBox "publicly" so I can change the properties from another method?

I tried it like this:

```
PictureBox canvas = new PictureBox
{
  Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
  BackColor = Color.Red
};

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  canvas.BackColor = Color.Red;
} // Now I can use "canvas" in other methods without any errors but still nothing happens
```

Comment: You have to add the picture box to your form. See the designer file of your form for examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's good start:

```
PictureBox canvas = new PictureBox
{
  Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
  BackColor = Color.Red
};

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  canvas.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

But you have to add that box to your form:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Controls.Add(canvas);
}
```

Once it's working as expected, you should call `canvas` field like that: `_canvas` as this is private field of this class (form).